# jcs 1.3 configuration with maven

Tags: maven, jcs

I want to add jcs to my maven project.

Under Configuration on the following page : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/faq.html

> What jars are required by JCS?
>
> As of verison 1.2.7.0, the core of JCS
> (the LRU memory cache, the indexed disk cache, the TCP lateral, and
> the RMI remote server) requires only two other jars. concurrent
> commons-logging Versions 1.2.6.9 and below also require the following
> two additional jars: commons-collections commons-lang All of the other
> dependencies listed on the project info page are for optional plugins.

When I add the jcs dependency (jcs version 1.3) to pom.xml , a lot of dependent jars are getting added to my classpath. I only need core jcs and its required dependencies, nothing more.

Is it possible to configure maven to have only the required dependencies and avoid the optional ones.

*Tried google for a solution , but could'nt find any information.

Answer (score 0):

What jars exactly are you talking about?

You should notice that you should use `<groupId>org.apache.jcs</groupId>`
and not `<groupId>jcs</groupId>`which doesn't mark optional dependencies.

You should receive the following dependencies.

[image]

Notice that the dependencies under commons-logging are transitive dependencies and thus are not counted by JCS as direct dependencies.

If for some reason you'd like to remove any of those dependencies you can use [maven exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)